# Set checkboxes checked depending on input values

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple checkboxes:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1100" class="myClass">
  </div>
</form> 
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="0011" class="myClass">
  </div>
</form> 
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1010" class="myClass">
  </div>
</form>
```

after getting their values in an array like this:

```
var arr = $('.myClass').map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).get();
// output: arr(3) [ "1100", "0011", "1010" ]
```

How can I set checkboxes checked where input value 1?
This is what I tried but it apply the first value for all checkboxes:

```
$(':checkbox').prop('checked', function(index) {
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var set = arr[i].split('')
    return +set[index] === 1;
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't appear to have any checkboxes. It's also not entirely clear what you're attempting to do; how does the array relate to whether or not the checkboxes should be checked? Your last paragraph implies you want to set the values of the checkboxes instead...?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the array has anything to do with getting the value of a checkbox, but if you add an id (such as id="myForm" to your form, then you can easily use:

```
<form id="myForm">

<script>
var getVals = $("#myForm input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
</script>
```

getVals would get the value of any checked checkbox in that form.